# Add option and save it - event wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a stuck, I add option `type event` to event post, i hope my event is normal or special. This is my option.

[image]

I dont know how to insert type into database, please help me. 
I'm trying so hard to show you my stuck, hope you help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Change the below listed values :

1. YOUR_POST_TYPE_NAME
2. YOUR_CUSTOM_FIELD_NAME

---

**Example:**

```
add_action('save_post_YOUR_POST_TYPE_NAME', 'some_function');

function some_function($post_id)
{
    $slug = 'YOUR_POST_TYPE_NAME',
    if ( $slug != $_POST['post_type'] ) {
        return;
    }
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'YOUR_CUSTOM_FIELD_NAME', '');

}
```